# Showing 1/x is continuous on (0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that 1/x is continuous on (0,1]. However I am not sure if my way is the correct way, because it seems like I am showing that 1/x is continous everywhere which is not the case.. Here is my try

$|f(x)-f(c)|=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{c}|=\frac{|x-c|}{xc}$

So given $\epsilon >0 $ we can choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{xc}$

And then $|x-c|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{xc}xc=\epsilon $

for $x,c \in (0,1]$

Comment: Your $\delta$ should not depend on $x$.

Comment: $\frac 1x$ is continuous every except at $x = 0$ where it is not defined.  As $x=0$ is not a concern it'd be fine.  However as Sobi points out $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ can not depend on the value of $x$.

Comment: At least not on both $x$ and $c$. You need to choose one of them (let's say $x$) and find a $\delta$, which doesn't depend on $c$, so that for any $c$ with $|x-c|<\delta$ above inequality holds.

Comment: @Sellerie While this is true, I feel that it would be very confusing and unconventional to keep $x$ fixed and let $c$ vary.

Comment: What is $c$?  Supposedly $c$ is an abitrary point in (0,1] at which we are proving it is continuous there (and as it could be any point it is continuous at all points).  In which case we can define $\delta$ in terms of $c$ but not $x$.  I hadn't considered that and so Sellerie was correct in pointing it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would start by being a little bit more explicit regarding what $c,x$ represent.

$\forall c\in(0,1], \forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0, \forall x\in(0,1]: |c-x|<\delta \implies |f(c) - f(x)|<\epsilon$

Next I would say something like let $\delta<\frac {c}{2}.$ Then $x>\frac {c}{2},$ and $xc > \frac {c^2}{2}$

$|\frac 1c - \frac1x| = |\frac {x-c}{xc}|<\frac{2|x-c|}{c^2}$

Now I see that when $c\in (0,1]$ I have created a bit of redundancy as

$\frac {c^2}{2} < \frac {c}{2}$

When $\delta = \frac{c^2\epsilon}{2}$

$|x-c| < \delta \implies |\frac 1c - \frac1x| = |\frac {x-c}{xc}|<\frac{2|x-c|}{c^2} <\epsilon$

Comment: That should be $\delta = \frac{c^2\min\{\epsilon, 1\}}{2}$ to cover the cases $c\epsilon > 1$, no?

Answer (score 2):

Your $$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{xc}$$ should not depend on your variable $x$.

Also in dividing by $cx$ you are assuming that $c\ne 0$ so you are not proving continuity everywhere which is good.

Comment: thank you, so I should let delta depend on c and $\epsilon only?$

Comment: yes, that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't have your $\delta$ dependent on $x$ as this must be true for *all* $x$ within $\delta$ of $c$.  The concept "all $x$ within $\delta$ of $c$" would be meaningless if the value of $\delta$ changes for different values of $x$.

So for any $c \in (0,1]$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ we need to find a $\delta$ (based an $\epsilon$ and maybe on $c$; but not on $x$ which we haven't picked yet) so that for any $x\in (0,1]$ where $|x - c| < \delta$ it will have to follow that $|\frac 1x - \frac 1c|< \epsilon$.

If  $|x - c| < \delta$ then $-\delta < x-c < \delta$ and $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$. If we assume that $c-\delta > 0$ (we'll have to deal with $c-\delta \le 0$ later...) then $\frac 1{c+\delta} < \frac 1x < \frac 1{c - \delta}$.

This would imply $\frac 1{c + \delta} - \frac 1c= -(\frac 1c - \frac 1{c+\delta}) < \frac 1x - \frac 1c < \frac 1{c-\delta} - \frac 1c$ and that $|\frac 1x - \frac 1c| < \max (\frac 1c - \frac 1{c+\delta}, \frac 1{c-\delta} - \frac 1c)$.

$\frac 1c - \frac 1{c+\delta} = \frac {\delta}{c(c+\delta)} < \frac {\delta}{c(c-\delta)} = \frac 1{c-\delta} - \frac 1c$ so if we had managed to define $\delta$ is such a way that $\frac 1{c-\delta} - \frac 1c \le \epsilon$ we would be done.

And to do that $\frac 1{c-\delta} - \frac 1c = \frac {\delta}{c(c-\delta)} \le \epsilon$ would mean $\delta \le \epsilon c(c-\delta)\epsilon$ or

$\delta + c\delta*\epsilon \le c^2 \epsilon$ or

$\delta \le \frac {c^2 \epsilon}{1+ c\epsilon}$ will do.

But we have to worry about $\delta < c$ .... but that can't happen as $\delta = \frac {c^2 \epsilon}{1+ c\epsilon}= \frac {c}{\frac 1{c\epsilon} + 1} < c$.

That's it.  If $\delta = \frac {c}{\frac 1{c\epsilon} + 1}$ then we can prove that if $|x - c| < \delta$ then $|\frac 1x - \frac 1c| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I think there is a minor typo on the fifth line counting upwards. It should be $\delta \le \epsilon c (c-\delta)$. ie it has an extra $\epsilon$